# T/R switch IC - HMC784AMS8GE IC does not work properly

Tags: electrical-engineering, rf-electronics

I want to use a T/R switch IC to select the filters. So I made a small board test HMC784AMS8GE IC like the schematic below:

[image]

The input (IN1) is the sine signal. But when I test, both OUT1 & OUT2 have the same signal as IN1 and both outputs (RF1, RF2) are always ON. Although, I changed the Control pin (A, B) following the datasheet. It means the RF switch inside the IC did not work properly when adjusting the value of the control inputs(A, B). Could you help me to solve this problem? Thank all guys.

Comment: R1, 2, 3 & 4 are short-circuiting the 5 V supply. Are you removing two of them to make the selection?

Comment: Yes. I use resistors to select logic values for IC. I do not use( R1 & R3) or (R2 & R3) at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Per the datasheet *"RF1 and RF2 are reflective shorts when “OFF”"*. For best results consider the following configuration.

[image]

Also per the datasheet below is the suggested interface for logic signal A and B

[image]

I suggest try using TTL logic to drive the logic signals

**References:**

- [HMC784AMS8GE GaAs MMIC 10 WATT T/R SWITCH DC - 4 GHz](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/hmc784a.pdf)